# Replacing the Modified input fields with Original values on clicking "Cancel" button

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2

I have a form, which when loaded retreive the members profile details from the table and display in the form, the user can alter the form fields and save using  "Update profile" button, this functionality is working fine. But when the user clicks on "cancel" button the modified values should be replaced with the original once i.e., when we reload the page. Cancel button should just replace the modified with the original onces without reloading the form.

Here is the snippet of the form field

```
<div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" >Last Name</label>
<div class="controls"><input id="lastName" type="text" 
value=" <s:propertyvalue="#currentMember.memberlastname" escape="false"/>"
name="member.memberlastname"/>
```

we use struts2 in our project

Answer (score 1):

Unless I miss understand you, this is pretty simple.  Just don't submit the form with the cancel button.  Are you using the `<s:submit/>` tag for the cancel button?  If so, don't, use an `<s:url/>` tag for the cancel action.

Comment: I am using input tag for cancel button.  When i click on cancel it should change to default values(i.e, the one from DB)

Comment: If you want to use the input tag, then you can do something like this:  `<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='<s:url action='cancel'/>'">`